# How can i show/hide image with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a logo image that in page load is hidden. I'd like that the image would show after page scroll.

Tried that approach:

CSS:

```
#logo {
    display: none;
}
```

JS/JQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >=100){
            $('#logo').show();
        } else {
            $('#logo').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Case 1: if page is loaded with scroll = 0, after page scroll logo image doesn't show.
Case 2: if page is loaded with scroll > 100, logo image is show or hidden correctly.

Comment: I didn't get the problem. Your code works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/97rv406j/  Is there something additional you want to achieve?

Comment: @Armin Yes, you're right. But, after some testing i realize that other scripts are in conflict. I'm working with Worpress and i've installed a theme and some plugins...

Comment: I can't help you much with that, that should probably be a new question with "wordpress" tag. I can suggest trying to deactivate/uninstall plugins one by one to see which one is interfering, but only if you know how to safely do it.

Comment: @Armin, it's a JQuery conflit with a theme script. I'll dig this further.

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine on scroll. If you just need to also conditionally hide/show the image based on the scroll position when the page loads, you can call the hide/show code when the page loads as well as when you scroll the page.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function hideShow(scroll) {
    if (scroll >= 100) {
      $('#logo').show();
    } else {
      $('#logo').hide();
    }
  }
  hideShow($(this).scrollTop());
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    hideShow($(this).scrollTop());
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh;
}
#logo {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" id="logo">
```

Comment: it seems that i've a conflict with other scripts.